# speaker option enabled by default when answering the calls

Tags: calls, speakerphone

Can any of the applications change the call settings? All of a sudden have observed that when an incoming call is answered, Speaker is enabled by default.

After uninstalling some of the applications related to calls, it became normal.
But I would like to know what/which caused the change in settings.
Apps I deleted are TrueCaller, [Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hcHBzdGFyLmNhbGxyZWNvcmRlciJd).

Any information related to this is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Samsung Galaxy Note 2 running 4.1.2 JellyBean.

Comment: I have this exact same issue on my HTC One, but I never had either TrueCaller or Call Recorder installed. It still persists now. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I know for certain that some apps do have the option of changing the setting (e.g. [InDrive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codesector.indrive&hl=en) allows you to switch to speakerphone when driving)

As for the second question, I believe that CallRecorder is the culprit, because:

a) I have tried TrueCaller once, and did not experience anything like you are mentioning,

b) Call recorder apps generally can't work on unrooted Android (as far as I know) unless you are using the speakerphone, so that they can record your voice, and the voice coming from the speakerphone.

Comment: That might be the case. But it all worked well before. Is there any setting that can be changed in the stock android, for default speaker phone? Didn't find any such thing in 'Call Settings'

Comment: Can you check in the settings of SVoice for a "Drive Mode"? If so disable it. That may be the issue. I'll keep looking for other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Wear Speaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wearableloudspeaker.com.wearableloudspeaker) is another culprit.