# Loud speaker on my HTC One turns on almost every time I answer an in coming call

Tags: calls, htc-one, volume

My HTC One is about 18 months old. On almost every incoming call I receive, the loudspeaker turns on. Other than the fact you look like an idiot saying 'Hello' only to have your phone on the loudspeaker as if you don't know how to work the thing, it's actually pretty sore when you get a full blast 'HELLO' directly into your ear. I'm wondering if it's an Android issue or specifically an HTC One thing.

I honestly can't remember if it happened directly after an update, and I don't really have any odd apps, at least none I think would affect in-coming calls anyway.

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46650/speaker-option-enabled-by-default-when-answering-the-calls?rq=1) is very similar to mine, but the apps which were un-installed to rectify the problem, are not and have never been on my device.

What is the possible reasons for this, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the default behavior of the M7 or M8; I've used both.

The way I see it, it's one of the following:

1. Some option in HTC's phone app or system settings has been enabled to invoke this behavior. I'd suggest reviewing the settings to confirm this isn't the case.
2. You may be experiencing some troubles with your touch screen. It's possible the touch digitizer is registering false positives, effectively tapping areas of the screen without you doing so.
   You may want to check that touches are registering correctly by using an app similar to [Yet Another MultiTouch Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rn.yamtt) and selecting the Paint Tester option. If touches are registered without actually touching the screen, this may explain the odd behavior.

I hope it's not the latter!

Comment: Cheers Paul, the second option never entered my head! I really hope it's not that, but I'll be sure to investigate. And I've checked and unchecked and and every option I could find relating to calls and none have had any effect.

Comment: There also exists the possibility that you're tapping the loudspeaker button with your cheek. Perhaps give that a test as well; does it go straight to loudspeaker without even holding it?

Comment: Concerning touch problems: does it only occur when plugged in? Cheap chargers often aren't grounded properly, which may cause the touch screen to go haywire.

Comment: My first thought was that it was my beard which was triggering it, but I've tested it at every angle and even experimented with my girlfriend (who has very little facial hair) and the problem persists. And I would generally remove the charger cable if I was about to answer a call.

Comment: If you are actually cheek-tapping, you could try to turn off the display by pressing the power button after picking up the call. This makes sure the display stays off when you're actually talking. Secondly, see if there is any helper options turned on under Settings > accessibility.